Why does my LED bulb light up dimly when I touch it?
I have a "Corn" LED light bulb very similar to this one on my bedside lamp:

It is one of these salt crystal lamps:

As you can see it has the salt crystal on top, then a part made of wood, and the bulb is in a hole below, in a socket that is connected directly to the wall (230V 50hz AC)
If the switch is off I realised that the light will turn on very dimly whenever I:

touch the crystal
touch the wood
take the bulb out of the crystal and touch the bulb
wrap my hands arround the wire

However, nothing happens when:

I touch the wire (touching only, not putting my hand arround it)
I wrap my hand arround the wire below the switch (on the wire that connects the switch to the wall)
the bulb touches something metalic, independent of said metal being in contact with me or not
I touch the plastic socket

Also when it is lit up dimly it will increase brightness if:

I touch more parts of it or combine the hand on the wire and touching the bulb
I touch something metallic that I believe is isolated (my bed frame and parts of the bedside table)
I grab the wire with more force

and it decreases brightness when:

I touch something metalic that I believe is grounded (metalic parts of another, different, bedside lamp or a metalic tap/faucet)

Another detail is that all of this works only on one position of the wall plug - if I flip the plug, that is, switch the holes that each prong enters, it stops behaving like this, and works like a regular bulb that only turns on when the switch is turned on.
Some final details: as I've said, the lamp is plugged directly into the wall so I believe there must be a rectifier somewhere in the socket or the bulb. All of this only works when the switch is turned off.
From my very small background in electronics, I can guess it maybe has something to do with my body forming kind of a capacitor with the wires, but I am not sure how that might work...
Can anyone explain why and how does this happen?

Yes, you are absolutely correct. Keep in mind these facts:

Any two conductive objects separated by an insulator is by definition a capacitor, so there is capacitance.

And, humans are just basically bags of conductive saltwater.

Even a small bit of stray capacitance means a small leakage current will flow through the capacitance.

LED lamps will light up visibly at extremely small currents.


… and cheap LED bulbs are so cheap that they don't even try to have any circuitry to prevent lighting up from small leakage currents.
So what happens is that when all the stars are aligned properly, i.e. the plug just the "right" way plugged in to socket, the switch may either cut the Live AC wire or the Neutral wire at zero potential.
If Live AC goes to lamp then any capacitance added to the disconnected neutral will light up the LED by a small amount.

So, it increases in intensity when I touch isolated metal because I'm increasing my capacitance by having more charge avaliable?
And why does it decrease brightness when I touch something that is grounded? Also, how does it work even if I touch the wood, since it is an insulator?

Also, is this dangerous in any way?

@SamFF If you touch something else you increase capacitance, more area for more capacitance. I can't know further why it sometimes increases or decreases but it's all about AC through capacitance but also you are a resistor so the DC potential of what you touch is important. It should not be dangerous, unless you directly touch the parts that have or may have mains potential on them.


Another detail is that all of this works only on one position of the wall plug - if I flip the plug, that is, switch the holes that each prong enters, it stops behaving like this, and works like a regular bulb that only turns on when the switch is turned on.

One advantage of polarized plugs is that the switch can cut the live wire rather than the neutral. In this case depending which way you plug it in the switch can cut the neutral meaning the bulb is live and all that voltage is looking for a bit of stray capacitance to make a path back to neutral. If the switch cuts the live the bulb is not at high voltage and touching it does not produce a current unless you stick your fingers into the electric socket.
It's not necessarily dangerous (LEDs can light up visibly with nanoamp currents so no reason to assume the leakage is practically significant), but if it were me I'd orient the plug so that this doesn't happen anyway just in case.
